# CRM 2016 Reports: Some dataset are blank when the report is ran with a specific user

Tags: sql, visual-studio, report, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a report on CRM 2016 which runs perfectly when it is launched with admin user. However, when we launch it with a normal user, all the datasets are displayed perfectly, except for 1 dataset (which was added lately to the report). To note that all the stored procedures used by the datasets (including this new one) have the same security roles on the SQL database. In addition, when I run the report from the visual studio, all the datasets are displayed as well. Can someone please help?

Comment: If you are querying with filtered views, this is expected based on crm security role & privileges. Check the sec role of that particular user.

Comment: the same security role is set on all the datasets. yet, the problem is on 1 dataset onlt. the report displays the other datasets which have the same security role

Comment: Any team membership, ownership you have ?

Comment: Did you try to run the VS with that particular user & see the result?

Comment: Can you show some code, screenshot of dataset / report you are talking about?

Comment: This SP is selecting rows from entity or view or filteredview? Also am not talking about DB role, CRM security role.

Comment: It selects rows from filteredview, like all the other SPs that are running perfectly well with the same user.

Comment: Login to CRM with Sys admin privilege, check the sec role of user in issue, verify if the role is having privilege for that particular entity

Comment: Yes, the role does have privilege for the particular entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was a security role issue on the business unit level

Comment: Glad that you are able to sort it out.